# The archive: /common-entity/target/common-entity-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've updated my project from SVN and refreshed the project in my eclipse IDE. When I was trying to run the test case, its throwing the following error.

```
The archive: /cu-common-entity-generated/target/common-entity-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

Earlier common-entity-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar was available, when I updated and ran maven again, a new JAR with other snapshot was updated. common-entity-7.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

This is my classpath

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/common-entity/target/common-entity-7.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" sourcepath="/cu-common-entity-generated"/>
```

Why is still referring to 1.0.0 snapshot? Is it the problem of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath of the JUnit *Run Configuration* (in *Run > Run Configurations* select the run configuration and see tab *Classpath*) instead of the classpath of the project. It seems the JUnit Run Configuration uses not the default but its own classpath.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: In _Run > Run Configurations_ select the run configuration and see tab _Classpath_